# htaccess Issue : Header throwing 404 although page is correctly displayed

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, googlebot

I am facing quite a strange problem at the moment, I have wordpress and oscommerce installations on single domain. I placed wordpress at the root and oscommerce in /store/ folder.
Everything is working properly except one thing. The server headers of oscommerce are throwing a 404 error although the page is displayed correctly. This results in a situation that googlebot will not index these pages at all.
Can anybody help me to resolve this issue? What should I do now?

```
Root httaccess is 

RemoveHandler .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^outdoorwatersolutions.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.outdoorwatersolutions.com/$1 [L,R=301]


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

and oscommerce httaccess is

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 # RewriteBase instructions
 # Change RewriteBase dependent on how your shop is accessed as below.
 # http://www.mysite.com = RewriteBase /
 # http://www.mysite.com/catalog/ = RewriteBase /catalog/
 # http://www.mysite.com/catalog/shop/ = RewriteBase /catalog/shop/

 # Change RewriteBase using the instructions above 
 RewriteBase /store/
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-p-([0-9]+).html$ product_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-c-([0-9_]+).html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-m-([0-9]+).html$ index.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pi-([0-9]+).html$ popup_image.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pr-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-pri-([0-9]+).html$ product_reviews_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
 # Articles contribution
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-t-([0-9_]+).html$ articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-au-([0-9]+).html$ articles.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-a-([0-9]+).html$ article_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
 # Information pages
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-i-([0-9]+).html$ information.php [NC,L,QSA]
 # Links contribution
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-links-([0-9_]+).html$ links.php [NC,L,QSA]
 # Newsdesk contribution
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-n-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nc-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_index.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nri-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_info.php [NC,L,QSA]
 RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/-]+)-nra-([0-9]+).html$ newsdesk_reviews_article.php [NC,L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I don't think you'll get much help unless you show your .htaccess file or httpd.conf (whichever is the problem).

Comment: You might try serverfault.com to get help configuring your web server.

Comment: I don't think it is an .htaccess issue. Are you sure that the code doesn't print out a 404 header for some reason?

Comment: then what it might be ? page is displayed properly, but if server header is accessed for oscommerce, 404 error is encountered, what will you say then?

Comment: According to what I googled, search engine safe urls in oscommerce causes this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like an oscommerce misconfiguration. Other people have had similar issues. Try some of the solutions [here](http://www.oscmax.com/forums/oscommerce-2-2-installation-help/3962-getting-404-error-when-trying-view-products.html) or google for more examples.

The link won't work for some reason, sorry. Here is the cached page I was trying to link to http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:Z2i_KItzGHcJ:www.oscmax.com/forums/oscommerce-2-2-installation-help/3962-getting-404-error-when-trying-view-products.html+&cd=9&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=firefox-a

Answer (score 0):

( I know it´s two years later... but maybe it saves time for anybody )

I had the exact problem on an oscommerce shop.
Just the product sites where showing like they should,
but giving a **header http 404 code**.

So I looked into the **product_info.php**
and there was something like this:

```
if ($product_check['total'] < 1) header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
```

I was like: what the hell !
It actually had been placed there to actually improve SEO performance...

( That bad advise has been given here:
http://forums.hostgator.com/oscommerce-enhancement-t27840.html
)

What it actually can do is killing your SEO works...

( Cause when a product is sold out it will signal that it´s gone
although it might be back later... )